# Python: What does assigning multiple variables to another variable mean

Tags: python, methods, overriding, variable-assignment

I am Python newbie. Trying to understand a particular statement where a function parameter is assigned to two variables. The following is code snippet from pyscard library for Smart Cards:

```
# a simple card observer that prints inserted/removed cards
class PrintObserver(CardObserver):
    def update(self, observable, actions):
        (addedcards, removedcards) = actions
        for card in addedcards:
            print("+Inserted: ", toHexString(card.atr))
        for card in removedcards:
            print("-Removed: ", toHexString(card.atr))
```

I want to know what does the statement mean:

```
 (addedcards, removedcards) = actions
```

Thanks.

Comment: `actions` is some type of container (list, tuple, etc.) with two elements, which are assigned to the variables `addedcards` and `removedcards`

Comment: `a,b = [5,6]` => `a=5` and `b=6`

Comment: Perhaps I can think of it as a list containing 2 lists as elements. In case the list contains more elements, only the first 2 will be assigned. Thinking out loud.

Comment: This is know as unpacking an iterable container, such as a list or a tuple.

Comment: I knew previous about function returning multiple variables where you would say e.g. x, y = dosomething() but first time learning about list/tuple unpacking.

Comment: @Malik: Functions that "return multiple values" (with `return x, y`) are actually just returning one value, a `tuple`, which can be unpacked.